# Embedding SQL Server ssrs report to asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2012, reportviewer

I am embedding SQL Server reports in an asp.net page. But am little confused with the code that I have:

```
reportViewerSam.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
reportViewerSam.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://DontKnowWhatToAddHere/ReportServer");//http://+:80/ReportServer
reportViewerSam.ServerReport.ReportPath = @"D:\TP\TestProject\Movies";
reportViewerSam.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

I am not sure what to supply to `reportServerUrl`. When I opened my `rsreportserver.config` file, I have following url:

```
<Application>
    <Name>ReportManager</Name>
    <VirtualDirectory>Reports_FA</VirtualDirectory>
    <URLs>
        <URL>
            <UrlString>http://+:80</UrlString>
            <AccountSid>S-1-5-80-1142752433-3704371676-891461080-4200684315-3208225222</AccountSid>
            <AccountName>NT Service\ReportServer$FA</AccountName>
        </URL>
    </URLs>
</Application>
```

I need to know what path should I give to `reportserverurl`

Comment: It looks like you are running reportserver on your localhost. 

So I guess: http://localhost/ReportServer

Comment: go to all programs -> microsoft sql server 2008 r2 -> Configuration Tools -> Reporting Services Configuration Manager. once u opened it click web service url tab and look in bottom part the URL is displayed there

Comment: @EuphoriaGrogi now I am getting error for `reportpath` that:"The path of the item '/D:/TP/TestProject/Movies' is not valid. The full path must be less than 260 characters long; other restrictions apply. If the report server is in native mode, the path must start with slash. (rsInvalidItemPath)"

Comment: @Alex i suspect that this is because of limitation of filename length limit in windows, try to shorten your path